# how to implement pagination for my website?

Tags: javascript, html, load

is there a way to let the database know I only want about 12 posts instead of all of them? I know im bringing in an array and I want to know if there is a spot in this code where I can put [0,11] in it somewhere to let it know that i only want the first 12 items in the array.

```
    app.get("/buy", function(req, res){
if(req.query.search && req.query.search!="All Tools"&& req.query.keyword){
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.keyword), 'gi');
    tool.find({drop: req.query.search, desc: regex}, function (err, sometools){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
        res.render("buy", {tools :sometools});
        }
    });
}
else if(req.query.keyword){
        const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.keyword), 'gi');
        tool.find({desc: regex}, function (err, sometools){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else{
            res.render("buy", {tools :sometools});
            }
        });  
    }
else if(req.query.search && req.query.search!="All Tools"){
    tool.find({drop: req.query.search}, function (err, sometools){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
        res.render("buy", {tools :sometools});
        }
    });
}
else{
    tool.find({},function(err, alltools){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.render("errorpage");
        } else{
           res.render("buy", {tools: alltools});
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here for anyone to help you. Do you own the database? Does the api you are using accept page parameters?

Comment: im coding on cloud nine using js, html, and css with Mongobd

Comment: is there a quick, dynamic way I can make a different rout for each page that only displays a certain amount of posts.

Comment: https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/